# As in web3.js get the same signature as the signature from the signTypedData_v4 method?

Tags: web3js, metamask, signature

I have a standard typed data object that uses Metamask, according to this scheme(without JSON.stringify):

[image]

If you sign such an object like this:

```
let sig = web3.eth.accounts.sign(JSON.stringify(order), secret_key, true)
```

then the resulting signature will differ from the signature obtained when signing a similar object in the Metamask by the signTypedData_v4 method. Therefore, I want to get a signature in web3js similar to a Metamask. How can I do this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5):

```
let sig = web3.eth.accounts.sign(JSON.stringify(order), secret_key, true)
```

You are signing a JSON string, which is not correct as per `EIP712` specs

You need to sign:

```
keccak256(
  abi.encodePacked(
    '0x1901', // EIP-712 prefix
    DOMAIN_SEPERATOR // a.k.a hash of domain
    hashStruct // hash of data to sign, definition - https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-712#definition-of-hashstruct
  )
)
```

Following are a few of the examples:

- [openzeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/1b27c13096d6e4389d62e7b0766a1db53fbb3f1b/contracts/utils/cryptography/ECDSA.sol#L207-L218)
- [eth-sig-util (metamask)](https://github.com/MetaMask/eth-sig-util/blob/73ace3309bf4b97d901fb66cd61db15eede7afe9/src/sign-typed-data.ts#L376-L417)
- [ethers.js](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/master/packages/wallet/src.ts/index.ts#L135-L148)

Answer (score 4):

From [MetaMask Docs](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/signing-data.html), we find the following JavaScript example of `signTypedData_v4`. I think this is the only way to implement `signTypedData_v4` in web3. Otherwise, you'll need to use MetaMasks's [`signTypedData(...)` method from eth-sig-util](https://github.com/MetaMask/eth-sig-util/blob/main/src/sign-typed-data.ts#L510).

```js
const msgParams = JSON.stringify({
    types: {
      EIP712Domain: [
        { name: 'name', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'version', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'chainId', type: 'uint256' },
        { name: 'verifyingContract', type: 'address' },
      ],
      // Not an EIP712Domain definition
      Bid: [
        { name: 'name', type: 'string' },

      ],
      // Refer to PrimaryType
      Mail: [
        { name: 'from', type: 'Person' },
        { name: 'to', type: 'Person[]' },
        { name: 'contents', type: 'string' },
      ],
      // Not an EIP712Domain definition
      Person: [
        { name: 'name', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'wallets', type: 'address[]' },
      ],
    },
});

var from = web3.eth.accounts[0];

var params = [from, msgParams];
var method = 'eth_signTypedData_v4';

web3.currentProvider.sendAsync(
    {
      method,
      params,
      from,
    },
    function (err, result) {
      if (err) return console.dir(err);
      if (result.error) {
        alert(result.error.message);
      }
      if (result.error) return console.error('ERROR', result);
      console.log('TYPED SIGNED:' + JSON.stringify(result.result));
    }
)
```